# Is "bis Ende nächsten Monats" a correct expression?

Tags: genitive, adjective-ending

If run English→German translation on google translator,

> Nevertheless, I wish this work could be finished by the end of next month.

I get

> Trotzdem wünsche ich mir, dass diese Arbeit bis Ende nächsten Monats abgeschlossen sein könnte.

Why is it not *"bis Ende des nächsten Monats"?*

Comment: Why is it `end of next month` and not `end of the next month`? I strongly recommend against GoogleTranslate (although it does an ok job this time). Try [deepL](https://deepl.com) instead.

Comment: @infinitezero Ah, thanks you. deepL translates it to `Ende des nächstern Monats` even though I omitted 'the' from 'end of the next month'. google translator missed `des` because I missed `the`. (if you can post an answer, I can choose it as the selected answer.)

Comment: I'm with @infinitezero when it comes to translators. Also I noted that the English original omits "the" in "next month" as well. So, can I suppose that the question is "when can I omit the article in a case like Ende + timespan.", is that correct ?

Comment: @ChanKim: Have a look, there are several answers that might serve your question in: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44675/omitting-an-article-before-countable-nouns and the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Is “bis Ende nächsten Monats” a correct expression?**
  Yes.
- **Why is it not "bis Ende des nächsten Monats"?**
  You have to ask the developers of Google Translator. Other translating machines like deepl produce what you want:

  > Dennoch wünsche ich mir, dass diese Arbeit bis Ende des nächsten Monats abgeschlossen werden kann.

Fact is, that all of these variations are correct and mean the same:

> bis Ende nächsten Monats
> bis Ende des nächsten Monats
> bis zum Ende des nächsten Monats

It's just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question "Personal taste" is insufficient, imo. There's more to it, like ellipses.

Comment: @a_donda The question is "is it correct". That is answered. Further, if there's a choice of different phrases which all are correct and with identical meaning: it's a matter of style and personal taste which to choose. What else?

Comment: @a_donda: Chan asked exactly 2 question, and I answered both of them precisely. That personal taste would be insufficient is a matter of your personal taste. But you are welcome to write a better answer. Use less energy to criticize others. Try to do better yourself instead.

Comment: Yes. Allmost everything in the world is a matter of personal taste. That's whataboutism. But it is not an answer to a question that asks "why".

Comment: @a_donda: Why do you think it wouldn't be a matter of personal taste? Please explain the rules that you should apply to distinguish between the three versions. Which of them is better? which is worse? and why? - It in fact is **nothing else than just matter of personal taste.** Others (like deepl) have chosen another alternative, and there also is a third version that is neither worse nor better than the two other versions. And it's only up to your personal style and taste which of them you will use. They are all correct and they all mean the same. You can freely choose between them. ...

Comment: ... I just can repeat: You are welcome to write a better answer. Use less energy to criticize others. Try to do better yourself instead.

Comment: I am at it, but good answers take time and need clarification. The question probably has already been answered with "when can the article be omitted". Am waiting for OP to approve the remarks.

Comment: thank you all for trying to give me a most 'correct' answer. :) I think I learned the `des` here can be omitted like we can omit `the` in English in some cases(including personal taste). That's what I was curious about.